# CKAN: context not being passed to new template

Tags: python, ckan

In my CKAN extension, I'm adding a new tab to the user dashboard. I followed the procedure described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20438872) and it seemed to work. In the controller for the new page, I set the template variables in the same way as they are set for the other pages on the dashboard. When I click on the tab and load the new page, though, I get `UndefinedError: 'user_dict' is undefined`. What's going wrong?

Here's the relevant part of **my_extension/templates/user/dashboard.html** where I add the tab:

```
{% ckan_extends %}

{% block page_header %}
  <header class="module-content page-header hug">
    <div class="content_action">
      {% link_for _('Edit settings'), named_route='user.edit', id=user.name, class_='btn btn-default', icon='cog' %}
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      {{ h.build_nav_icon('dashboard.index', _('News feed')) }}
      {{ h.build_nav_icon('dashboard.datasets', _('My Datasets')) }}
      {{ h.build_nav_icon('dashboard.organizations', _('My Organizations')) }}
      {{ h.build_nav_icon('dashboard.groups', _('My Groups')) }}
      {{ h.build_nav_icon('my_extension_dashboard_owned_datasets', _('My Owned Datasets')) }}
    </ul>
  </header>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the new template so far, **my_extension/templates/user/dashboard_owned_datasets.html**:

```
{% extends "user/dashboard_datasets.html" %}
```

The relevant part of the plugin class definition:

```
class MyThemePlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin, DefaultTranslation):

    plugins.implements(plugins.IRoutes, inherit=True)

    # IRoutes

    def before_map(self, map):
        with SubMapper(
            map, controller="ckanext.my_extension.controller:MyUserController"
        ) as m:
            m.connect(
                "my_extension_dashboard_owned_datasets",
                "/dashboard/owned_datasets",
                action="dashboard_owned_datasets",
            )
        return map
```

And here's the new controller, in **my_extension/controller.py**:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import logging

import ckan.lib.base as base
from ckan.common import c
from ckan.controllers.user import UserController

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

render = base.render


class MyUserController(UserController):
    def dashboard_owned_datasets(self):
        context = {"for_view": True, "user": c.user, "auth_user_obj": c.userobj}
        data_dict = {"user_obj": c.userobj, "include_datasets": True}
        self._setup_template_variables(context, data_dict)
        log.critical(c.user_dict)
        return render(
            "user/dashboard_owned_datasets.html"
        )
```

As you can see, I use the `UserController`'s `_setup_template_variables` method, which is used in all the other dashboard actions in that controller. That method sets `c.user_dict`, among other things:

```
def _setup_template_variables(self, context, data_dict):
    c.is_sysadmin = authz.is_sysadmin(c.user)
    try:
        user_dict = get_action('user_show')(context, data_dict)
    except NotFound:
        h.flash_error(_('Not authorized to see this page'))
        h.redirect_to(controller='user', action='login')
    except NotAuthorized:
        abort(403, _('Not authorized to see this page'))

    c.user_dict = user_dict
    c.is_myself = user_dict['name'] == c.user
    c.about_formatted = h.render_markdown(user_dict['about'])
```

I'm logging `c.user_dict` after setting it in the controller, and I see all the data I would expect to see there.

But when I click the tab and load http://localhost:5000/dashboard/owned_datasets, I get the error `UndefinedError: 'user_dict' is undefined`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the `IRoutes` plugin interface no longer works for what I want to use it for, due to the migration of CKAN from Pylons to Flask. The `IBlueprint` interface should be used instead. See https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Migration-from-Pylons-to-Flask#flask-views-blueprints-and-routing for more information on blueprints and how to convert an extension from using `IRoutes` to `IBlueprint`.